# What to do after Postgres bigserial run out?

Tags: postgresql

I have a client who has about 11 million records of data per year.
I am using bigserial as my id.

My question is, if it runs out of usual numbers, what shall I do next?

I am sorry I am a noob in Postgres.

Comment: Think about it for 9223372036854775807 / 11000000 = 838488366986 years.

Comment: By the time this happens you can probably switch to a bigger data type: MultiSerial, MegaSerial, UltraSerial, M-M-M-MONSTERSERIAL.

Comment: Is there multiserial in postgres?

Answer (score 3):

Bigserial numbers are integers from 1 to 9223372036854775807 (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html)). By inserting *one hundred millions records each year*, you will run out of numbers after 92233720368 years. That is, more than 92 billions of years.

Quite a large span of time, as you can see.

Comment: I see. So it is quite impossible. I wonder does search engine use auto increment as key?